# How to find end points of a line in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, line, point

I am trying to figure out how to find the end points of a line. Lets say that I have a line that goes from `(0,0) to (2,2)` in a `cartesian` coordinate system and `opencv` sees the line using Probabilistic Hough Line Transform, how do I find those 2 points?

I know that hough line transform finds lines by matching up points, but how do I use that line and find the two points that make up that line?

Are there any functions that are already built into the library that provides this functionality?

I'm using `OpenCV 2.4.3` in `C++` in

```
VS Studio 2010
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [`HoughLinesP`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlinesp#houghlinesp):

> lines – Output vector of lines. Each line is represented by a
>   4-element vector (x1,y1,x2,y2), where (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are the
>   ending points of each detected line segment.

There's even example of usage.

Comment: I checked out the example code, that is exactly what I need. Thank you so much.